# Calculate the integral where $P_{n}$ and $P_{m}$ are Legendre Polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials, legendre-transformation

Calculate the folowing integral:
$$I_{k,m}=\int_{-1}^{1} x(1-x^2)P'_{n}(x)P'_{m} dx $$

So, my attempt to solve this consisted in:
First, I thought of manipulating the folowing relations so i could get $x(1-x^2)P'_{n}(x)P'_{m}$ in function of only $P_{n}(x)$, $P_{m}(x)$, $m$ and $n$ so I could use the ortogonality property

$(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)+nP_{n-1}(x)-x(2n+1)P_{n}(x)=0$

$nP_{n}(x)+P'_{n-1}(x)-xP'_{n}(x)=0$

$(1-x^2)P'_{n}(x)+xnP_{n}(x)-nP_{n-1}(x)=0$

But, I couldn't get rid of x or ended up with the derivatives still in the formula.

My other idea was to use integration by parts:

$u=(1-x^2)P'_{n}(x)$

$du=((1-x^2)P'_{n}(x))'dx=n(n+1)P_{n}(x)dx$

$dv=xP'_{m}$

And i used integration by parts again to find $v$ but it only got more complicated and still had the derivatives on the formula.

Can anyone help me solve this? I would aprecciate ideas on how to start solving it.

Comment: I’m fairly certain that if you substitute with the recursion, expand, and integrate by parts twice it works. I can’t write up the full proof at the moment because I’m at a birthday party but I will do so when I get home.

Comment: I'd really aprecciate it if you did, I've been wrecking my brain trying to solve this. While you don't respond, I'll try to see if your method works by myself. Thank you anyways! @person

Comment: Sorry for the late response, this was considerably more difficult than I assumed while I wrote my comment. I had to wait until the morning until I could finish my solution.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use the fact that the Legendre polynomials are complete. In  other words, the sum:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nP_n(x)$$

can converge to any function $f$ with finitely many discontinuities in $[-1,1]$. Knowthing this, we have:
$$\int_{-1}^1f(x)P_m(x)dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_{-1}^1P_nP_mdx=a_m\frac2{2m+1}$$
By orthogonality. If $f$ happens to be a polynomial with degree smaller than $m$, then $a_m$ will be $0$, and so the integral of the product of a polynomial with $deg(f) < m$ and $P_m$ will be $0$.

Starting from here, first assume WLOG that $n\geq m$ we can use the substitution you proposed: $(1-x^2)P'_{n}(x)=(n+1)xP_n(x) − (n + 1)P_{n+1}(x)$, and arrive at:
$$I_{n,m}= \int_{-1}^1x(1-x^2)P’_n(x)P’_m(x)dx=n\int_{-1}^1x((n+1)xP_n(x) − (n + 1)P_{n+1}(x))P’_m(x)dx $$
Expand and we have:
$$(n+1)\int_{-1}^1x^2P_{n}(x)P’_m(x)dx - (n+1)\int_{-1}^1xP_{n+1}(x)P’_m(x)dx$$
Consider the first integral. If we approximate $x^2P'_m(x)$ by a sum of Legendre polynomials, it will have no terms with $a_kP_k(x)$ where $k > n + 1$, as it is degree at most $n+1$. Therefore, if $n>m+1$, the first integral will vanish by orthogonality.

Similarly, the second integral is $P_{n+1}$ times a polynomial of degree at most $n$, and so it cannot have any terms in it's series representation with Legendre polynomials, $a_kP_k(x)$ where $k \geq n+1$. So regardless of what $m$ is, the second integral always vanishes.

This means, we have:
$$I_{n,m}=(n+1)\int_{-1}^1x^2P_{n}(x)P’_m(x)dx$$
With only two possible values of $m$, namely: $m=n$, $m=n-1$, or the integral is $0$. Let's start with the second case. If $n=m+1$, then we can use one of the equations you found, namely $nP_{m}(x)+P'_{m-1}(x)-xP'_{m}(x)=0$:
$$I_{n,m}=(n+1)\int_{-1}^1x^2P_{n}(x)P’_m(x)dx=I_{n,n-1}=(n+1)\int_{-1}^1xP_{n}(x)(nP_{n-1}(x)+P'_{n-2}(x))dx$$
$$=n(n+1)\int_{-1}^1xP_{n}(x)P_{n-1}(x)dx+(n+1)\int_{-1}^1xP_{n}(x)P'_{n-2}(x)dx$$
Now the second integral can be evaluated to be $0$ by once again considering that $xP'_{n-2}(x)$ has degree $n-2$. As for the first, we can use the recursive definition of the Legendre polynomial to get:
$$=n(n+1)\int_{-1}^1P_{n-1}(x)\frac{(n+1)P_{n+1}(x)+nP_{n-1}(x)}{2n+1}dx$$
And now once again by orthogonality, we have at last:
$$=\frac{n^2(n+1)}{2n+1}\int_{-1}^1P^2_{n-1}(x)dx=\frac{2n^2(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$
Now for the first case, where $n=m$:
$$I_{n,n} = \int_{-1}^{1} x(1-x^2)(P'_{n}(x))^2dx$$
The trick now is to use even/oddness. The integrand is a product of two even functions and an odd function ($x$), so the integrand is odd, and integrating an odd function over a symmetric domain will result in $0$. Therefore, this case as well, will be $0$. The only non - zero case is therefore:

$$I_{n,n-1} = \frac{2n^2(n+1)}{(2n+1)(2n-1)}$$

Final comments: I was very mistaken to think that this was doable via simple methods  quickly. Hopefully someone else can find a simpler/faster method. Sorry for any typos, this is quite the long post and I probably managed to make an arithmatic mistake somewhere along the way.